# Django: How to write a GET query, using values_list attribute?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to query a model, for single instance (eg., `id=1`), but I only want to return the value of a single field (`'title'`). I can achieve this with the following query:

`SomeModel.objects.filter(pk=1).values_list('title', flat=True)`

But a `get` is more efficient than a `filter`. However, `values_list` and `values` don't work with `get` queries. Ideally, I would prefer to do this:

`SomeModel.objects.get(pk=1).values_list('title', flat=True)`

But I get the following error: `AttributeError: SomeModel has no attribute 'title'`

**What is the best way write this query?**

Comment: You probably should not need worry about the perfomance between `filter` and `get`. What really matters is that you don't perform 1+N queries. Your current code almost looks like you are executing this query for various keys. If this is the case you should either perform a join or use `pk__in=[1,2,3,4,5]` to fetch the titles of more than one object at the same time.

Comment: Also OP doesn't need to worry about the performance difference between `filter` and `get` because there isn't any ;)

Comment: Unless, I suppose, OP is trying to work with multiple rows… In which case, `get` *will* be faster because it will throw an exception right away!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But a `get` is more efficient than a `filter`.

This is simply not true. A `.get(…)` will generate *exactly* the same SQL as a `.filter(…)`.

Using:

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(pk=1)[0:1].values_list('title', flat=True)
```

Will do what you want, and will have exactly the same performance characteristics as `.get(…)` (actually, it will be a bit faster, because `.get(…)` checks to see if more than one row would be returned…):

```
In [4]: import logging

In [5]: l = logging.getLogger("django.db")

In [6]: l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

In [7]: User.objects.filter(id=1)[0:1].values_list()
DEBUG:django.db.backends:(0.006) SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 1  LIMIT 1; args=(1,)
Out[7]: [(1, u'admin', u'Admin', u'User', u'admin@example.com', u'sha1$bf3bc$daa1fb58a8a41e15c730ae86bc0faf4c01fdd3a1', True, True, True, datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 8, 21, 15, 51, 855527), datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 10, 15, 13, 55))]

In [8]: User.objects.get(id=1)
DEBUG:django.db.backends:(0.001) SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 1 ; args=(1,)
Out[8]: <User: admin>
```

Comment: Django certainly does not use `LIMIT` for `get`. Otherwise it could never throw [MultipleObjectsReturned](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.MultipleObjectsReturned). `LIMIT 2` would be an option but this since you expect only one element to be returned this would just decrease the performance of the query.